# Angular Ui-grid add all columns in one click

Tags: angularjs, grouping, angular-ui-grid

I'm new to Angular and its ui-grid, plus, the ui-grid is relatively new compared to Angular, so documentation is more lean on it. There is so much to learn, and in all my searching I just can't seem to find some aspects clearly documented. Thus this question.

I'd like to give the user an option to add all possible non-displayed columns to the grid. How can I do that? Can this be added as an additional option in the dropdown where displayed columns are selected?

To be clear, I already have defined more fields than are displayed upon first load (several are hidden), but for convenience when working with columns it'd be nice to offer a one-click method to see them all.

As a bonus, I'd also like to offer an option to reset the columns displayed to the state they were in on load. I can maintain that state myself and can probably figure it out eventually, but as a bonus anything on this aspect would be welcome as well.

Comment: For the bonus section, have a look at the "save and restore state" feature, which will do what you want. http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/208_save_state

Comment: @S.Baggy Hey, that's a good idea. I was only thinking of that feature in terms of saving a user-customized state, but saving the system's initial state upon load is totally viable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To your question 1

There is a inbuilt option called grid menu. Using that you can set visibility of the columns to show.

But you need to pass the grid elements to your controller with visible false as initial load state.

Here is the [example given](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/121_grid_menu) from ui grid

To test it go to its plunker and change the column defns as it

```
 columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name',visible:false },
      { name: 'gender', enableHiding: false },
      { name: 'company' }
    ],
```

Sorry, not clear on the second part

Comment: I already have hidden columns. I want to programmatically, when the user clicks a button, show all available columns.